# Spring afterPropertiesSet invoke before Servlet init?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I want to do some database search after tomcat startup.

So I just implements `InitializingBean` and implement method `afterPropertiesSet` and put database operating in `afterPropertiesSet`.

And, my project is using `proxool`.

Then I startup tomcat to test `afterPropertiesSet` method. I got this error

```
org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ProxoolException: Attempt to refer to a unregistered pool by its alias
```

I thought its some thing wrong with the order of startup of the components in `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletConfigurator</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.configuration.ServletConfigurator</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>propertyFile</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/jdbc.properties</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProxoolAdmin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.admin.servlet.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ProxoolAdmin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/proxool/admin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:config/application-context-*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then I set one breakpoint at the first line of `afterPropertiesSet` method, the second breakpoint at the `init` method of `org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.configuration.ServletConfigurator`.

To avoid the error before, I just type a single print operat in `afterPropertiesSet`.

Then I startup tomcat to check the order of `afterPropertiesSet` and `ServletConfigurator`.

`afterPropertiesSet` method is invoked before `ServletConfigurator` init.

I have been figure out why I got `Attempt to refer to a unregistered pool by its alias` error.

But, How to let `afterPropertiesSet` invoke after `ServletConfigurator` init?

**EDIT**

And there is class `GoodsRecommendService`

```
@Service
public class GoodsRecommendServiceImpl implements InitializingBean {
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("There is invoked before servlet init!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am confused. You are registering a servlet yourself and it's also a Spring bean? What does `ServletConfigurator` extends from?

Comment: `ServletConfigurator` is a component of proxool, and the method `afterPropertiesSet` is not part of `ServletConfigurator`, its in another class

Comment: and where is that bean configured then and how does that relate to the servlet? Your servlets are managed by the servlet container, not by Spring.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll Ive been added class code, check it please

Answer (score 3):

The issue is being caused by the fact that `ServletContextListener`s are invoked before all `Servlet`s of the context are created. As the API for `ServletContextListener` [states](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29):

> Receives notification that the web application initialization process is starting.
>
> All ServletContextListeners are notified of context initialization before any filters or servlets in the web application are initialized.

So in your configuration:

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:config/application-context-*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

means that your Spring ApplicationContext is created before any of the Servlets. This is why you are getting your error.

To fix it you need to ensure that whatever you are trying to do in your bean, you do it once the Proxool servlet is properly initialised.

I think the easiest way to do this is to switch your Spring ApplicationContext to be loaded by DispatcherServlet and ensure that the load-on-startup value for DispatcherServlet is greater than that of the Proxool servlet.

For more information on DispatcherServlet, see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach might be to make sure Spring application context will configure Proxool, as in the following example:

```
  <bean id="proxoolProperties" class=" org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:proxool.properties"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="proxoolConfiguration" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
              <property name="targetClass" value="org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.configuration.PropertyConfigurator" />
               <property name="targetMethod" value="configure" />
               <property name="arguments" ref="proxoolProperties" />
  </bean>
```